# Kubernetes - Configure GMSA for Windows Pods and containers

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I need to setup a windows authentication in Kubernetes. And to configure GMSA in K8s for pods and containers in windows, I came across this link:-(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-gmsa/).

This documentation has a step which confirms to “**Install Webhooks to validate GMSA users**”. To follow this step a linux/unix script is asked to execute which generates certificates, private key and other values and substitue in YAML file which is further executed on a Kubernetes cluster. As mentioned in a screenshot below (part of mentioned link)

[image]

Now I have a Kubectl client installed on Windows machine and even all images created and deployed on windows container running on windows server 2019 only.

I cannot execute this unix/linux script to create Webhook from windows machine. Is there any other way to achieve this step.

Thanks

Comment: You can try installing [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server) and then run bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Cygwin (Linux Platform on Windows) to execute the script.